# Ask user to Save data code review

Tags: c#

When user clicks to exit form, and data are unsaved, I would like to ask user does he wants to save data. Can below code be more simplified, to be easier to read this method SaveOrRejectChanges().

```
private bool SaveOrRejectChanges()
{
    if (MsgBox("do you want to save data") == true)
    {
        if (ValidateIsEmptyOrNullValue()) return false; //here I check is required field not entered

        SaveChanges(); // if validation passes (data are entered), save it
    }
    else
        RejectChanges(); // cancel changes by setting EntityState.Unchanged on DBContext for each entity

    return true;
}

private void iExit_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    _isFormClosing = true;

    // close form if data are not modified (no saving required). Or close form when data are saved or changes are canceled 
    if (_isDataModified == false || SaveOrRejectChanges()) 
       this.Close();
}
```

I am still sort of beginner, so please share your thoughts. I kind of dont like nested if, but I had to put it inside of other if, as if it is before asking user, then it would simply cancel closing which I dont want of course. Please share your solution if you think of some. Thank you.

Comment: So what is your question, whats not working

Comment: TheGeneral, question is can code in method SaveOrRejectChanges() be more simplified, to be easier to read in that method. it has IF for asking user with MsgBox, then we had another if, its kind of more difficult to read

Comment: This `RejectChanges(); // cancel changes by setting EntityState.Unchanged on DBContext for each entity` worries me. Just dispose the context, you don't need any of that manual work. You can remove that `else` clause completely

Comment: To be honest, there is nothing really wrong with that method. well apart from the whole entity thing. we sometimes have to live with `if`s

Comment: thanks Camilo. In form closing event I have this code :  private void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;

            DbContext.Dispose();
        }  so DBContext is disposed when form is closed

Comment: Dont hold on to DbContexts, put them in a `using` statement or fear the wrath of your work mates and colleagues

Comment: TheGeneral, well, I am holding on DBContext while form is opened. Project is in Windows Forms so as long as form is opened DBContext is opened. When form is closed, DB Context is disposed. This is reccommended approach by Microsoft for WinForms, and it simplifies a lot saving data as data (binded controls on form) are tracked by entity framework tracker which tracks which field is modified and which is not, even for multiple records if needed.

Comment: `This is reccommended approach by Microsoft for WinForm` really? `and it simplifies a lot saving data as all it tracked by entity tracker` it saves you a couple of lines of code, and is less fault tolerant while introducing other problems. however on saying that, if this is a very quick lived form then.. well its debatable

Comment: TheGeneral, I found it on Microsoft website. I really tried with it for months for best way to do it, and with Windows Forms it is recommended approach. Of course for web forms it is not. It does not save only couple of lines of code. My code went from 1300 lines of code in form to 320. How much of saving is that ? Not to mention readability.

Comment: wow, I could not see forest from the tree. In SaveChanges() method I have same check if (ValidateIsEmptyOrNullValue()) return false; . I can simply delete it now from this code SaveOrRejectChanges()

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.SX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Code Review question.

The way you're coding is mixing logic code with GUI code. A much better approach is binding the Form Controls to a class.

This way you can easily unit test the business logic, even if it's just validating & saving the state of the controls.

The other benefit is if all the Form Controls state is saved in a class you can simply Serialise the class to Json, XML, dB, etc.

**Update:**

Here is a huge tutorial on using BindingSource Controls - DataGridView, TextBox & ListBox examples: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial.

So your logic is already in a business logic class, but you have a dependancy still on a Message Box. To decouple have an Action method or an EventHandler hooked up to call the GUI Form class, please note psuedo code written on my phone:

```
public class GUI {

   public BusLogic BL = new BusLogic();

   public GUI () {
         BL.ShouldSaveData += Should_Save_Data;
    }

    public bool Should_Save_Data() {
       DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("do you want to save data", "", MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel);
       return res.Ok == DialogResult.Ok;
    }

    private void iExit_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) { 
       _isFormClosing = true;

       if (_isDataModified) BL.SaveOrRejectChanges();
    }
}
```

In your business logic class you can invoke the ShouldSaveData() event.

```
public class BusLogic {

   public event Action<bool> ShouldSaveData;

   public void SaveOrRejectChanges() {
      bool confirmSave = false;

      if (ShouldSaveData != null) confirmSave = ShouldSaveData;

      if (confirmSave) //DO YOUR SAVING HERE
   }
}
```

This keeps the presentation and logic tiers decoupled.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Well, my database code logic is in Persistence layer. I have also UI layer. So, all regarding database is in database layer. And since some code is still dependent on UI layer, it has to remain in UI layer. I have extracted it in other class methods. However, yes, I do not know Serialise class to other types, its a bit advanced for me. I have barely 2 years of experience. Binding Form controls to a class, hmm, how to do it?

Comment: please check my refactored version reply, Saving and Rejecting changes code is in Persistence layer. However, I do not understand serialise concept and "Binding Form controls to a class"?  But, my form is actually binded to a class with BindindSource component which uses class from Persistence layer. However, I do not understand other parts which you mentioned.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have not used delegates yet, I have to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved code a bit, here is refactored version:

```
    private void AskToSaveChanges()
    {
        // note: MyMessageBox is a class in UI layer, because it uses UI component 
        // of Windows forms
        if (MyMessageBox.Show(MyMessageBoxActions.Save, ""))
            SaveChanges(); // this is done in Persistence layer
        else
            RejectChanges(); // this is done in Persistence layer
    }

    private void iExit_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        _isFormClosing = true;

        if (_isDataModified == false || AskToSaveChanges()) 
           this.Close();
    }
```